# case statement after where clause to omit the row of data if satisfied

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

Hi I have a table as below and I'm trying to extract the data from them if and only if the below condition is satisfied.

```
ID        Rank 
45689     1 
54789     2
98765     1
96541     2
98523     3
92147     4
96741     2
99999     10
```

If the ID starts with 4 and 9 or 5 and 9 and have same Rank then omit them. If ID starts with 9 and no matching Rank with other ID (starting with 4 or 5) then show them as result.

So My Output should look like

```
ID      Rank
98523     3
92147     4
99999     10
```

How can I use case statement in where clause to filter the data?

Comment: What does "and have the same rank" mean - same as what? Another row? *If the ID starts with 4 and 9* - how can a string simultaneously start with both a 4 and a 9? For each of your example input rows, put a comment saying why it did/didn't appear in the output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select only those ID that begin with a 9, and have a rank that is not also the rank of (another) ID that begins with 4 or 5. Is that correct?

The query below is for the case ID is of string data type (although it will work OK, probably, if ID is numeric data type - through implicit conversion).

```
select *
from   your_table
where  id like '9%'
  and  rank not in (
                     select rank 
                     from   your_table
                     where  substr(id, 1, 1) in ('4', '5')
                   )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `COUNT()` analytic function along with a conditional aggregation such as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(id,1,1) IN ('5','9') OR
                      SUBSTR(id,1,1) IN ('4','9') THEN 1 END ) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY Rank) AS count, t.* 
  FROM t -- your original table
)   
SELECT id, rank
  FROM t2
 WHERE count = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a982f2b8c24d8714690b6860893dce68)</kbd>

Comment: What will this return if two distinct ID's, both starting with 9, have the same rank? Assuming the same rank is not shared with ID's that start with 4 or 5, I believe the OP still wants them returned; I believe this query will not return them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function to only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT id,
       rank
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN id LIKE '4%' OR id LIKE '5%' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY Rank )
           AS num_match
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  id LIKE '4%'
  OR     id LIKE '5%'
  OR     id LIKE '9%'
)
WHERE  id LIKE '9%'
AND    num_match = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Rank ) AS
SELECT 45689,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54789,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98765,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 96541,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98523,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 92147,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 96741,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 99999, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>    ID | RANK
> ----: | ---:
> 98523 |    3
> 92147 |    4
> 99999 |   10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=264bcdfab841b5f0983640d7c3b116da)*